# CSS simple menu - how to align?

Tags: html, css

Got a newbie CSS question, just beginning to get into CSS so please bear with me. 
In my ASP.NET MVC app there's a menu:

```
<div id="menucontainer">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS styles for it:

```
ul#menu
{
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li
{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

#menucontainer
{
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can I make some of the li elements align left and the rest of them right in a single line?
Tried to break it into two menus and write two different styles, just can't seem to get the right css. Probably have to build a valid box model - any pointers on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two `<ul>`s, one with `float:left` and the other with `float:right`. That should do it.

Comment: ul#menu
{
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

ul#menu-right
{
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}          

This breaks my menu into two lines.

Comment: Take off the `width: 100%` then - that's making each `<ul>` take up the whole width.

Comment: It does kinda work now, only the menu now overlaps a main content div, which was below the menu before. What could cause that?

Comment: Managed. Added "<br style="clear: both;" />" after the menu div. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @pklonsinski: Yes, floats can cause all manner of layout issues with the following content. The best solution I know of is is this clearfix: http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2007/09/developers-note-2/

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods on how to do what you want. A List Apart has an [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/) about 6 different methods on how to do this.